# How to skip validation of object properties for type: [Object]

Tags: meteor, simple-schema

I'm trying to validate an Array of Objects with Simple-schema..

```
validate: new SimpleSchema({
    orderId: {type: String},
    skins: {type: [Object]}
}).validator(),
```

..but it seems that Simple-schema wants me to also validate every single property on every object inside that array, since i'm constantly getting "keyNotInSchema" type validationErrors:

```
skins.0.appid is not allowed by the schema
```

Is there any way to cancel validation of each object's property and to instruct Simple-Schema that i want just an "Array of Objects"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must declare that this is a [blackbox](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#blackbox) object:

```
validate: new SimpleSchema({
    orderId: {type: String},
    skins: {type: [Object], blackbox: true}
}).validator(),
```